# Core Data: How to update value of type NSSet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm developing an application that allows user to draw routes on map.
I have three entities:

[image: My entities]

User should be able to save `Track`, and then continue drawing it after a while. My problem is in updating - as i understood, to add `Track` objects to existing ones, i should fetch `TrackName`, update it's `Set<Track>` and save context(not sure about this one, is this right approach?). I store points that user draws in an array of custom type `Line`(it has same variable names as Track entity), but i don't know how to replace `Set<Tracks>` with `Array<Line>`. Is there any way to create array of type `Track`? Or can i add some kind of constructor for `Track`?

Right now i'm doing this:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrackName")
        var pred = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@ and username.userName == %@", trackName!, currentUser.login)
        request.predicate = pred
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        var result : NSArray = NSArray()

        do
        {
             result = try context.executeRequest(request) as! [TrackName]
        }
        catch{}

        var currTrack = result[0] as! TrackName
```

and trying to do something like this

```
currTrack.track = Set<Track>(arrayLiteral: trackPoints)
```

but trackPoints is other type.

Edit 1.

Pavel, i tried to do it this way, but found out that new TrackName and Name objects were created each time, and when i fetch tracks added i get empty array. code below:

first, user names his track

```
func logName(name:String)
    {
        var appDel : AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate);
        var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        var nameEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Name", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        var forName = Name(entity: nameEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        forName.userName = currentUser.login

        var trackNameEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrackName", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        var newTrack = TrackName(entity: trackNameEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        newTrack.name = name
        newTrack.username = forName
        do{
            try context.save()
        }
        catch{}
        trackName = name
    }
```

saving track:

```
func saveTrack()
    {
        var appDel : AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate);
        var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        var nameDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Name", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        var nameEnt = Name(entity: nameDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        nameEnt.userName = currentUser.login

        var trackNameDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrackName", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        var trackEnt = TrackName(entity: trackNameDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        trackEnt.username = nameEnt
                 var trackDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Track", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        for p in trackPoints
        {
            var newTrack = Track(entity: trackDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            newTrack.trackname = trackEnt
            newTrack.startLat = p.startLat
            newTrack.startLon = p.startLon
            newTrack.endLat = p.endLat
            newTrack.endLon = p.endLon

        do {try context.save()}

        catch{}
    }
    }
```

When i save like this and check .sqlite file, i see that new Name and TrackName are created.

fetching:

```
func fetchWithPredicate(table: String, pred: NSPredicate)->NSArray
    {
        var appDel : AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate);
        var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: table)
        request.predicate = pred//NSPredicate(format: pred)
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var results: NSArray = NSArray()
        do{
            results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        }

        catch{}

        return results
    }
```

fetchWithPredicate is called from here:

```
func getTrack(trackName: String)->[Track]
    {
        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "trackname.name == %@", trackName)
        return fetchWithPredicate("Track", pred: pred) as! [Track]
    }
```

it returns an empty array, but there are records in the .sqlite file

I think it's pretty much the same as you wrote. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: When you save, you are not setting the value for the `name` attribute of your `TrackName` object (`trackEnt`).  Hence it does not match the predicate in your fetch request.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, to add new `Track` you don't need to add it manually to `Set<Track>`. Instead, you just need insert new `Track` object in context, then set for it `TrackName`, and then save context, and it will work just perfectly, it will automatically update `TrackName` entity.

And yes, you can create some category for `Track` which will insert it in context and take data from `Line` or `trackPoints`

Comment: I edited the question, please check it.
Can you please paste a link about categories? I have no Objective-C background and i'm new to Core Data.